# Concatenar endereço no Objeto Range VBA Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Preciso concatenar um endereço no Objeto Range do Excel e não estou conseguindo.
O valor é uma variavel do tipo Integer.
Segue a linha de código:

```
Range("O10").Formula = "=SUM(O12:O" & "valor)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Public Sub Teste()
  Dim Valor As Integer
  Valor = 3000
  Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(D1:D" & Valor & ")"
End Sub
```